# Kotlin andoid pre poluate data base

Tags: android, database, kotlin, room

I am trying to build a really simple db to store the score of a Hangman game.

I built an entity :

> @Entity(tableName = "scores") data class DBScore(
> @PrimaryKey
> var pseudo: String = "",
> var score: Int = 0 ) {
>
> }
>
> //Conversion method to go from DB model to kotlin model fun
> List.asDomainModel(): List {
> return map {
> Score(
> pseudo = it.pseudo,
> score = it.score
> )
> }
>
> }

To prefill the db with sample values with a db file

> ```
>  INSTANCE = databaseBuilder(
>                     context.applicationContext,
>                     AppDataBase::class.java,
>                     "app_database"
>                 )
>                     .createFromAsset("database/scores.db").build()
> ```

I have created the following db file to do so : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c534dd62136c94f17c0ee71f1ef39a1920201011144837/6ff2b7

But I get an error and don't understand what is wrong with my db :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: scores(com.example.hangmangame.database.entity.DBScore).
Expected:
TableInfo{name='scores', columns={pseudo=Column{name='pseudo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, score=Column{name='score', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
TableInfo{name='scores', columns={score=Column{name='score', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, pseudo=Column{name='pseudo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Seems to be an issue with the order of the columns but for me SQL is not sensitive to it.

Thx for any help.

Regards

Quentin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Room is expecting `score` to be `NOT NULL`. Your pre-populated database schema has it as `NULL`, apparently, based on the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I didn't see it. I tried to change it in sqlite but I still have the same error.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1b7f77794f22c93e0356008211c0a65920201011172507/c29845

It seems that my modification are not taking into account by AS

Comment: It worked fine at just had to uninstall the app first to take the modification into account.